# Removing duplicates from the data

Tags: regex, r, duplicates

I already loaded 20 csv files with function:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list_of_data = lapply(tbl, read.csv)
```

I combined all of those filves into one:

```
all_data = do.call(rbind.fill, list_of_data)
```

In the new table is a column called "Accession". After combining many of the names (Accession) are repeated. And I would like to remove all of the duplicates.
Another problem is that some of those "names" are ALMOST the same. The difference is that there is name and after become the dot and the number.

Let me show you how it looks:

```
AT3G26450.1 <--
AT5G44520.2
AT4G24770.1
AT2G37220.2
AT3G02520.1
AT5G05270.1
AT1G32060.1
AT3G52380.1
AT2G43910.2
AT2G19760.1
AT3G26450.2 <--
```

`<--` = *Same sample, different names. Should be treated as one. So just ignore dot and a number after.*

Tried this one:

```
all_data$CleanedAccession = str_extract(all_data$Accession, "^[[:alnum:]]+")
all_data = subset(all_data, !duplicated(CleanedAccession))

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "CleanedAccession", value = character(0)) :
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicate row or just rename it by removing ".X".

Comment: I would like to remove rows with the duplicates (Accession) and remove accession with the same number before dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command to both subset and rename the values:

```
subset(transform(alldata, Ascension = sub("\\..*", "", Ascension)), 
       !duplicated(Ascension))

   Ascension
1  AT3G26450
2  AT5G44520
3  AT4G24770
4  AT2G37220
5  AT3G02520
6  AT5G05270
7  AT1G32060
8  AT3G52380
9  AT2G43910
10 AT2G19760
```

Comment: Working good. What about the second part ? Removing other "duplicates".

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
df  <- data.frame( Accession = c("AT3G26450.1",
                   "AT5G44520.2",
                   "AT4G24770.1",
                   "AT2G37220.2",
                   "AT3G02520.1",
                   "AT5G05270.1",
                   "AT1G32060.1",
                   "AT3G52380.1",
                   "AT2G43910.2",
                   "AT2G19760.1",
                   "AT3G26450.2"))

df[!duplicated(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Accession), 
   ".", fixed = T),  "[", 1))), ]
```

Comment: You could split on `'.'` and set `fixed=TRUE` to make this marginally quicker.

Comment: Error in strsplit(all_data, "[.]") : non-character argument. Forgot to mention that there are some other names instead of "AT3G52380.1".

Comment: The Accession variables are factors in you dataframe and strsplit expects a character argument. I've updated my answer to account for the factor variables and RoyalTS's suggestion.